# Convert image of a published phylogeny into newick format in R

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I need to use a published phylogeny for a subsequent analysis, and to do that, I must convert the tree from a pdf, jpg or tiff image to a machine-readable newick format. At the moment, I use the `locator` function to measure individual branch lengths in the image inspired by [this post](https://rdataviz.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/getting-data-from-an-image-introductory-post/) and I build the newick format manually. While this works, the process is costly and prone to errors.

Is there a more convenient and reliable way of using a published phylogeny for further research? I'm not looking for options of recalculating the phylogeny from the DNA sequence data.

Comment: I think this has been tried since phylogenies have been published and unfortunately doesn't work. Maybe the best would be to ask the author of the paper to share their phylogeny in a computer format rather than an image of it? I know this comment is not specially helpful though.

Comment: @ThomasGuillerme Thank you. Your comment was helpful in a way, as there is need to develop a wrapper.